# Ajax submits form twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

None of the cases in this forum helped me. I did all the cited options like

```
$(this).unbind("click");
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
return false;
$('form').unbind("submit");
onsubmit="return false;
etc...
```

I put tried those everywhere. None ow them worked for my case. Plz, help me I just stuck need to launch the project asap.

Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="payment">
  <fieldset id="pincode_fieldset" <?php echo ($user->pincode=="" ||      $user->pincode_error==3)? "disabled":""; ?>>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deposit" name="deposit">
    <a type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right">Pay</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<script>

//payment confirmation;
function confirmPayment(){

$("#username2").text($("#username").val());
$("#deposit2").text("€"+$("#deposit").val());
$('#confirmModal').modal('show');

$("#confirm_btn").click(function(e){
    $("#modal_content").hide();
    //$(this).unbind("click");
    submitForm('#payment','payment.php', true, true);
    //e.stopPropagation();  
});

$("#back_btn").click(function(){
    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#modal_content').show('slow');
    });
});
   //$('form').unbind("submit");
   return false;
}

$("#payment").submit(function(){
    confirmPayment(); 
    return false;
});

</script>
```

**case 1:**
When I click #submit_btn and click #confirm_btn form submits once;

**case 2:**
When I click #submit_btn and click #back_btn and click #submit_btn and click #confirm_btn form submits twice;

**case 3:**
if I do the action 3 times it submits three times

etc.

I checked with alert();
The problem is here:

```
$("#confirm_btn").click(function(e){
    $("#modal_content").hide();
    //$(this).unbind("click");
    submitForm('#payment','payment.php', true, true);
    //e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

submitForm() is submitting again and again depends on the clicks I have made on #submit_btn. I need to give users the option of confirmation before they submit. Please, help me I cannot solve it spend whole day and night.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to confirm that the user wanted to do what they just did?  Isn't that just annoying?

Comment: Yes because username must be sure. Otherwise transferred money cannot be returned.If there is typoo on the username and if that username exists the money will be mistakenly transferred to that username. Therefore I need the user double confirm before transfer money.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't sure by the very fact that they just entered a lot of data and clicked on submit?  (I could continue, but it quickly gets very annoying..)  I think your fundamental problem is that the `confirmPayment()` function both confirms, submits, and sets up event handlers (it's a bit hard to tell what's going on because your indentation is wonky).

Comment: You could take all the modal out of it and just say `$('#payment').submit(function () { return confirm("..."); });`.

Comment: Double check that you are not referencing any jquery or ajax libs twice.

Comment: This is just one example I used. I have lots of places where I need to use the same way for more complex payments in this project.

Comment: @thebjorn, yes you are right there is js way but for better way and comply with the project rules confirmation should be displayed on modal. Please give me the solution for the exact problem. I need to also know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, (i) cancelling the click on the `<a..>` element that works as a submit button, and (ii) binding the widget actions at the top level, with the modal/ok-button actually submitting the form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="payment" action="payment.php">
    ...
    <a type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right">Pay</a>
    ...
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#confirm_btn").click(function (e) {
        $('#payment').submit();
        $("#confirmModal").hide();
    });

    $("#back_btn").click(function () {
        $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
    });

    function displayModal() {
        $("#username2").text($("#username").val());
        $("#deposit2").text("€" + $("#deposit").val());
        $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
    }

    // clicking on the submit button shouldn't submit, but just 
    // display the modal. 
    $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
        displayModal();
        return false; 
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You are right. But I use ajax. submitForm('#payment','payment.php', true, true); is an ajax submit. Thank you anyway for your help. I solved myself given above.

Answer (score 0):

Last I solved the problem myself.
I just split the confirmPayment() into two and it worked:

```
<script>

//payment confirmation;
 function confirmPayment()
{
     $("#username2").text($("#username").val());
     $("#deposit2").text("€"+$("#deposit").val());
     $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#confirm_btn").click(function(e){
         $("#modal_content").hide();
         submitForm('#payment','payment.php', true, true);
     });

     $("#back_btn").click(function(){
        $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#modal_content').show('slow');
        });
    });

   return false;
 });

 $("#payment").submit(function(){
     confirmPayment(); 
     return false;
 });

 </script>
```